# Remove audio players from Xubuntu's sound menu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, audio-player

With several media players installed the XFCE Sound Menu can quickly become over populated – so how do you go about removing these entries? That's the question I've asked myself and have been trying for days to figure out. Unfortunately, most solutions on ask Ubuntu as well as on the internet are no longer applicable. For example:

```
com > canonical > indicator > sound > blacklisted-media-players
```

This may work for the Ubuntu Gnome Desktop, but does not for Xubuntu or any XFCE Ubuntu based derivative. If you are as annoyed as I am about that, I hope my solution will give you a piece of mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, I finally figured out how to resolve this. The dconf-tools method hasn't been working for me since I believe Xubuntu 16.04. That's because XFCE's sound menu no longer utilizes nor reads the g-settings from com > canonical > indicator > sound, hence why we don't even have this entry on Xubuntu anymore. Instead it has it's own entry within XFCE's Xfconf.To make a long story short, here's how you can remove and blacklist multiple players from the Xubuntu/XFCE sound menu:

Navigate to `/home/yourusername/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`. Scroll down to: `<property name="mpris-players" type="string" value="`. Add the ones you want blacklisted here in the following format: `[&apos;gmusicbrowser&apos;,&apos;vlc&apos;]`, it's best to add it at the end of the entry.

If you are new to Linux, follow the screenshots guide below:

Open your XFCE Settings Manager and navigate to `"Settings Editor" -> "xfce4-panel" -> "mpris-players"`.

Add the ones you want blacklisted here in the following format: `['gmusicbrowser','vlc']`. See screenshots.

[image: XFCE Sound Menu Audio Players]

[image: XFCE Settings Manager - Xfconf]

[image: Xfconf XFCE Panel Settings - Audio Players]

[image: XFCE Panel Settings - Where to Remove Audio Players]

[image: XFCE Panel Settings - Blacklist Audio Players]

[image: Voilà, no more VLC in the XFCE Sound Menu]

Et voilà, if excessive entries annoyed you, now you know how to get rid of them on Xubuntu and XFCE Ubuntu based derivatives.